# MySQL File Download Speed Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have all my files stored in a mysql database as blobs. I am trying to add a speed limit to the rate at which a user can download them through our PHP website. I have tried to use the "sleep(1);" method, it does not seem to work or i am not doing it right. So if anyone knows a way to limit the speed, i would love your help.

Here is my download code

```
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file_servers WHERE id='$file_server_id'");
        $fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $file_server_ip=$fetch['ip'];
        $file_server_port=$fetch['port'];
        $file_server_username=$fetch['username'];
        $file_server_password=$fetch['password'];
        $file_server_db=$fetch['database_name'];
        $connectto=$file_server_ip.":".$file_server_port;
        if (!$linkid = @mysql_connect($connectto, $file_server_username, $file_server_password, true))
        {
            die("Unable to connect to storage server!");
        }
        if (!mysql_select_db($file_server_db, $linkid))
        {
            die("Unable to connect to storage database!");
        }
        $nodelist = array();
        // Pull the list of file inodes
        $SQL = "SELECT id FROM file_data WHERE file_id='$file_id' order by id";
        if (!$RES = mysql_query($SQL, $linkid))
        {
            die("Failure to retrive list of file inodes");
        }
        while ($CUR = mysql_fetch_object($RES))
        {
            $nodelist[] = $CUR->id;
        }
        // Send down the header to the client
        header("Content-Type: $data_type");
        header("Content-Length: $size");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
        // Loop thru and stream the nodes 1 by 1
        for ($Z = 0 ; $Z < count($nodelist) ; $Z++)
        {
            $SQL = "select file_data from file_data where id = " . $nodelist[$Z];
            if (!$RESX = mysql_query($SQL, $linkid))
            {
                die("Failure to retrive file node data");
            }
            $DataObj = mysql_fetch_object($RESX);
            echo $DataObj->file_data;
        }
```

Comment: This is *not* how you throttle an internet connection, not what a DB engine is for.  I suggest reading up on the correct technology to use for this (and what that is depends on what you need).

Comment: First, all `mysql_` functions are deprecated. You should switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_` instead. Second, you should use things for what they do best. File systems are great for storing files and databases are great for storing data. You could store a file name though, so you know which file to retrieve from the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this may be the combination of [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) and sleep:

- read part of what you get from database
- output some bytes
- flush the output to the user
- sleep for 1 second

But also take a loot at throttle function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-throttle.php
It also have an example there. I think it is better suited.

Comment: Thx you so much i tried the sleep with the fluch the link you had said to use ob_flush and that made it work. :)

Answer (score 0):

it is in the very last echo line in your code where you would like to implement throtling. Im not familiar with whether php supports throtling output.

if not, you can try to split up that content (`$DataObj->file_data`) you wish to echo, and echo it little piece by little piece with small pauses in between

and be sure to disable outbut buffering. otherwise all that you echo will not be outputted until the entire script is done.